# how to update Sum of one column of table based on column of other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table A

```
_________________________________________
ILE No |Post Date |Opening Qty | In Qty| Out Qty|
-----------------------------------------
1       30/06/20               500.00
4       30/06/20               300.00
5       01/07/20               250.00
9       05/07/20               300.00
```

Table B

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Inbound Ent No | Outbound Ent No | Posting Date |Quantity|
----------------------------------------------------------
1                       0          30/06/20     500 
1                       2          01/07/20    -200
1                       3          02/07/20    -100 
1                       4          02/07/20    -50
4                       0          30/06/20     300 
4                       7          01/07/20    -50
4                       8          02/07/20    -100
```

I have above both tables with above structure and data.

I am taking user input @startdate 02/07/20. I am trying to count Sum of "Quantity" Field from Table B to update in Field "Opening Qty" of Table A based on A . ILE No = B . Inbound Ent No So in this example, if user enter @startdate as '01/07/2020', query should count Sum of Quantity
from table B, for ILE No. 1 as 300 (500-200).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a group by to do the sum on B and use this for an update on A.

```
UPDATE a
SET [Outbound Ent No] = t.[Total]
FROM TableA a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Inbound Ent No], SUM(Quantity) as [Total]
    FROM TableB
    WHERE [Posting Date] >= @startdate
    GROUP BY [Inbound Ent No]
) t
ON t.[Inbound Ent No] = a.[ILE No]
```

Comment: Thanks Randy for your reply, above query not working for me. for your reference below was my query

Comment: UPDATE a
SET [QtyOpn] = t.[Total]
FROM #TbStockSum a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Inbound Item Entry No_], SUM(Quantity) as [Total]
    From [Orbit_fish_19092020].[dbo].[Live- Orbit Fish-New$Item Application Entry] 
    WHERE [Posting Date] between '2020/06/30' and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, @Start_Dt), 0)
    GROUP BY [Inbound Item Entry No_]
) t
ON t.[Inbound Item Entry No_] = a.[ILE_No]

Comment: basically, if user enter date as say, Start date 10/07/20 and end date as 23/11/20, i want to calculate opening quantity (i.e sum of Quantity started from 30/06/20 up to 09/07/20 (1day before start date). ILE_No is stored in my #TbStockSum, same also available in my Table Item Application Entry.. still its not working